# Filling incremental unqiue values for a newly created PK

Tags: sql, db2

I currently have a table with many rows, but no PK at all. I now require to have a unique, non-null, > 0 PK for every row.

I'm created the column for PK, but how I can I quickly fill in the column with an incremental value starting from 1?

Any method, a single SQL line, or a SQL line to be executed as many times as are rows are good enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
update sometable set newkeyfield = Row_Number() Over();
```

should do not a DB2 bloke, but should be close.

Comment: I've tested your solution, google the error message and fixed the sql for it to work under DB2. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using a DB2 [Sequence object](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0004201.html).  They are designed for creating unique sequences of numbers.  Pick your data type.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE mySeq as int;
```

You retrieve and increment the sequence in one step, using a [sequence reference](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0023464.html)

```
NEXT VALUE FOR mySeq
```

You expression can use this in an INSERT, UPDATE, or MERGE, or most places you can use an expression.